# Sending payments through PayPal API without paying the fees

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

We would like to send PayPal payments automatically via API with the same functionality like the regular send-money feature on the web-version, meaning:

a) The recipient pays the fee

b) We can send the payment with the credit card attached

I'm aware of the MassPay API, but as far as I know it requires the sender to pay the fee and can only be paid for by PayPal balance.

Is there an API that works like described?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Payouts, the current version of the old MassPay API, requires a PayPal balance or bank funding source (in the countries where it's available).  It cannot be used to send money from a card.

Whether the sender or the receiver pays the transfer fee is semantics: if the receiver were to be paying it, they are consequently simply receiving less than the gross amount that was sent to them. This semantic distinction only exists in the web version, not with the Payouts API.

Comment: Couldn't this API be used to send payments where the recipient pays the fee?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/

Comment: That API doesn't send payments, it sets up a checkout. If you are going to go through a checkout, may as well use the regular send-money web-version